# How to Apply Backstretch to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I know this is a Dumb question, but I don't know where to place this code on Wordpress

```
/*
 * Here is an example of how to use Backstretch as a slideshow.
 * Just pass in an array of images, and optionally a duration and fade value.
 */

  // Duration is the amount of time in between slides,
  // and fade is value that determines how quickly the next image will fade in
  $.backstretch([
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"
  ], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

And does this have to be between the script tags? Or in the PHP code?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
CODE
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, backstretch appends a div within the one you targeted it to do so.
Also, javascript is a client sided language. No need to do this in PHP.

Simple answer: Add it between two script tags, client sided, after loading in jquery.

Comment: Except WordPress already enqueues jQuery...so doing so would mean it's loaded twice. And if the OP decides to use the jQuery that comes with WordPress, he/she will need to be made aware that the `$` jQuery shortcut won't work by default. The actual, correct way to add this would be to add it to its own file, and enqueue it properly using `wp_enqueue_script()`, with `jquery` as a dependency.